# Is there a way to set a control color to an hexadecimal value strictly via VS designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

One will find plenty of answers as to how to do it in runtime, the most concise I came across being using `ColorTranslator.FromHtml(#FFFFFF);`, which I have been using so far.

I am specifically searching for a way to do it at design time, in Visual Studio's form designer. Is there one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter a hex color for color properties at design time by prefixing the color code with `#`. For example:

- `#FFFFFF` will be converted to `White`
- `#FCFCFC` will be converted to `252, 252, 252`

Comment: You could also use RGB values separated by a comma for example blue-ish color: `16, 109, 202` or white: `255, 255, 255`. You can just type or copy paste it in the `BackColor` or `Color` property.

Comment: @Jan Yes, you can also write name of known colors. However, the point of the answer is just letting know the OP that they can type hex format of color as well.